# VBA dynamic validation of text box based on selection in drop down menu

Tags: excel, vba

all. I have a table in the worksheet called **lookupMisc** called *periodNo (A)* and *periodName (B)* with the following values.

```
A   B
1   09:00
2   10:00
3   11:00
4   12:00
5   13:00
6   14:00
7   15:00
8   16:00
9   17:00
```

The code for this as follows:

```
   For i = 1 To ws_misc.Range("periodNo").Rows.Count
        CombinedName = periodNo(i, 1) & " - " & periodName(i, 1)
        cbo_period.AddItem CombinedName
    Next i
```

and thsi generates:

[image]

Now you will notice that there is a **Length** (**txt_length**) text field to the right. Basically I am trying to create a form of dynamic validation based on the entry that period has. Here are the cases:

```
If user selects  Then
1 - 09:00        Length can only accept values from 1-9
2 - 10:00        Length can only accept values from 1-8
3 - 11:00        Length can only accept values from 1-7
4 - 12:00        Length can only accept values from 1-6
5 - 13:00        Length can only accept values from 1-5
6 - 14:00        Length can only accept values from 1-4
7 - 15:00        Length can only accept values from 1-3
8 - 16:00        Length can only accept values from 1-2
9 - 17:00        Length can only accept values from 1-1
```

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: When do you want to validate, upon command button, or upon entry?

Comment: I would like to validate on entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
if me.txt_length.value<1 or me.txt_length.value>10-clng(left(me.cbo_period.value,1)) then
    msgbox "Entry must be between 1 and " & 10-clng(left(me.cbo_period.value,1))
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just put data validation in the length cell that is based on the value that is selected in the drop down:

[image: DataValidationExample1]

[image: DataValidationExample2]

Good Luck.